# How to see the result from link tracking using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

i read the article from Google
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863

and i use the URL builder tool to build the link.
But the question is , where can i see the result?
It just said "these parameters are sent to your Analytics reports"
but I don't know where to see it.

I'm new to Google analytics . Hope someone can explain it more to me.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Mira, this is off topic/not a good question for stackoverflow (since it is not about programm code but about how to read a report). This would be a better fit for webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your manually tagged campaigns under Acquisition > Campaigns.

(Friendly reminder to post only coding questions to SO, as previously commented.)